# jQuery plugin for making a center focus carousel

Tags: html, css, jquery

I'm converting a psd file to html and I'm stuck here. Can someone show me a jQuery plugin with example code that can make a carousel with center focus and slider buttons like what is shown below?

[image: This is the carousel]
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gONY8.png)[image: HTML code][image: jquery]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**slick**](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) is a jQuery responsive touch carousel.

#### Features

- Fully responsive. Scales with its container.
- Separate settings per breakpoint
- Uses CSS3 when available. Fully functional when not.
- Swipe enabled. Or disabled, if you prefer.
- Desktop mouse dragging
- Infinite looping.
- Fully accessible with arrow key navigation
- Add, remove, filter & unfilter slides
- Autoplay, dots, arrows, callbacks, etc...

#### Center mode

In center mode the picture in the middle is larger than the other pictures on either side.

[image]

#### Center mode example code

```
$('.center').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: tks #karel but I wonder how to ajust its position

Comment: 1. [How do I position one image on top of another in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474/how-do-i-position-one-image-on-top-of-another-in-html) 2. [CSS z-index Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: I've follow its usage but it didn't work

Comment: Save a copy of the code you used (in plain text, not a screenshot), the results that didn't work, and maybe make a screenshot to make it clearer what happened. Then ask about how to fix it in [Stack Overflow Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/), but you have to show some code or else the question will be off topic at Stack Overflow. good screenshot of the three black images.

Comment: By the way. To use this plugin we must set (css) the position we want for each div first or the plugin automatically do that. (I've attached code and js above)